# CSS Grid - Stretch to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to create a simple 3 column layout like this...

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col1 {
background:red;
text-align:center;
}

.col2 {
background:yellow;
text-align:center;
}

.col3 {
text-align:center;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col1">
    Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>

  <div class="col3">
    Column 3
  </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to change things so that the center div is only as wide as the image it contains, then `col1` and `col2` stretch to fill the remaining space.

Anyone have an example they can show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grid-template-columns:1fr auto 1fr;
```

Here you go, use the `auto` instead of `1fr` for the centered div.

Answer (score 4):

Change `grid-template-columns` to `1fr auto 1fr` - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  /* changed */
}

.col1 {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.col2 {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}

.col3 {
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}

img {
  display: block; /* remove inline element "space" below image */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>
  <div class="col3">
    Column 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below snippet.

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr auto 1fr;
}

.col1 {
background:red;
text-align:center;
}

.col2 {
background:yellow;
text-align:center;
}

.col3 {
text-align:center;
background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col1">
    Column 1
  </div>

  <div class="col2">
    <img width="300px" height="300px" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  </div>

  <div class="col3">
    Column 3
  </div>

</div>
```